# Can raspberry Pi 3 and Lidar lite v3 connecting without resistor in circuit?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I recently try to use Lidar Lite v3 with my Rpi 3, and it works with I2C communication. My wiring method is due to offical documentation. [image: Wiring picture] **However, what I have learned before is that the gpio pin of RPI can only afford 3.3v working voltage.** My Question is that shouldn't I add the resistor in my circuit to prevent from breaking out the pins of my RPI ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your concern is that the SCL and SDA pins run at 5V because the device is powered with 5V.

Page 4 of the operation manual, under heading I2C interface paragraph 2

"*The I2C bus operates internally at 3.3Vdc*"